# Capturing Stack Trace with CXF Handler

Tags: java, websphere, cxf, handler, stack-trace

I have not been able getting CXF 2.7.x's `Handlers` to work with WebSphere v7 (web services without Handlers do work accordingly), however, I wanted to know whether it is possible to access the stack trace, if thrown by a web service, via CXF's `Handler` (not Interceptor)?

Namely, if I implement `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>`, would I be able to capture the stack trace in `public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext ctx)`, via, say, `ctx.getMessage().getSOAPBody().getFault()`?

Normally, when an exception is thrown, I see a brief description in the fault detail of SOAP response, so I do not know whether `SoapFault` object would contain information about the stack trace in the first place!

The reason I am asking is, before being able to get CXF Handler working with WebSphere, I need to know whether seeking a stack trace in `handleFault()` is a viable option to begin with or am I going down the wrong rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to have CXF JAX-WS services to have the stack trace available in the `Handler` is to have the option enabled in the config file, i.e. *Spring*'s:

```
<cxf:bus>
  <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
      </cxf:features>

      <cxf:properties>
     <entry key="faultStackTraceEnabled" value="true" />            
  </cxf:properties>
</cxf:bus>
```

However, if you wish to only have access to the stacktrace content but not to send it back to the service consumer, you have to manually/programmatically obtain `<stacktrace>` Element and set its content to empty, or better, remove the Element itself.